# How to store certain sheet or how to delete all sheets except certain?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel, maatwebsite-excel

This is what i'm trying to do

```
Excel::load($file->getRealPath())
->getSheet(0)
->setFilename(Auth::user()->id_user)
->store('xlsx', storage_path('import'));
```

Instead of ->getSheet(index) I also trying ->selectSheetsByIndex(index)

Always there is an error

> Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::setFilename()

What I'm doing wrong? Documentation on the official Maatwebsite is incomplete and there are no examples of popular use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the maatwebsite-excel implementation, but according to it's website it's based on PHPExcel.

And the PHPExcel I'm using (can be found on packagist, https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel) doesn't have any function setFilename() in class PHPExcel_Worksheet or its interface PHPExcel_IComparable.

Perhaps the documentation of PHPExcel can help you (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).